# Create Pull Request from branch1 to branch2

Tags: git, github

I have two branches `branch1` and `branch2`, both created from `master`. I need to create a Pull Request on GitHub from `branch2` to `branch1`.

**Is that possible without `branch2` being created from `branch1`?**

If possible, which command is relevant to this?

Comment: you'll maybe find your awnser here : https://yangsu.github.io/pull-request-tutorial/

Comment: @charlesLgn That tutorial among others only talks about pushing to master.

Comment: What's the problem you foresee/fear? Why would it *not* be possible? Did you try it?

Comment: @RomainValeri Yes, I've created a sample copy with small commits. `git push <branch1> <branch2>` doesn't work. Until now I have only encountered having to push to a local branch while the actual Pull Request part is done with GitHub's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can !

Even the branches are not created from one another, one can raise PR.

[image: PR]

Above is the screenshot created and verified on Github after branch1 and branch2 are created from master and trying to raise PR.